# Resource localization: use of x:Uid referring to another assembly's resource

Tags: xaml, windows-8, localization, visual-studio-2012, winrt-xaml

I am writing a win8 application and will be using the built-in resource management system: `resw` file and `x:Uid` tags in my XAML code.

So I create let's say a `TextBox` like that:

```xml
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}" x:Uid="ResourceTest"/>
```

I create the corresponding resource file in my assembly with a `ResourceTest.Text` entry and it works fine: proper text is displayed at runtime.

Now, I would like to move all my resx files to another C# Library for maintainability. So I put the resources file in a brand new project and reference this new assembly from the main assembly.

But this causes the previous construct to fail (no text is displayed).

However, if I programmatically retrieve the resource value using the following code from inside the side assembly (called ResourcesLibrary), I get the string correctly:

```cs
static ResourceLoader resourceLoader = null;
public static string GetString(string resourceName)
{
    if (resourceLoader == null)
        resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader ("ResourcesLibrary/Resources");
    return resourceLoader.GetString (resourceName);
}
```

**How do I enable the `x:Uid` mechanism when dealing with out-of-assembly resources?**

I tried a few things in the `x:Uid` such as `ResourcesLibrary/Resources/ResourceTest` but with no luck.

Comment: Have you found the solution since asking the question? I'm facing the same problem right now.

Comment: nope, I fell back to using the same assembly, didn't have time to investigate.

Comment: Actually we've ended using this tool for generating code-behind class for resw resource file, works like a charm even when the resw is in another assembly: http://reswcodegen.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem for a long time. But after testing a little bit, I solved it by writing the whole Path of the Resources in the XAML Code.

Something like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="/ResourcesLibrary/Resources/ResourceTest" />
```

Unfortunately this answer came very late, but may it can help other persons.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting this.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you can't use x:Uid if the resources are maintained in a .resx file.

if you use .resw files you can access the strings whatever the assembly they are residing in.

they can be accessed as you mentioned in your question  like this "ResourcesLibrary/Resources/ResourceTest"