# Load "loose" localized resources at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, internationalization

I have a web service which supplies me with a generated .resx (XML only) which I then convert to binary a `.resources` file.  I am currently generating an assembly file with that using `al.exe`.  Here are my arguments:

```
/t:lib /c:{culture} /embed:"{.resource input}" /out:"{.dll output}"
```

Loading this assembly in via `Assembly.LoadFrom(file)` works fine, but I believe that my assembly is not properly generated. It has no type, namespace, or methods to invoke and therefor no `ResourceManager` apparently.

Essentially I am just wondering if it is at all possible to generate, load, and utilize resources that have no class or namespace which my project knows about at compile time. Thanks.

Comment: Not answering your concern, too involved for me unfortunately. But if you have a clue about my issue, maybe it's related: [my SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929590/resource-localization-use-of-xuid-refering-to-another-assemblys-resource).

Comment: I have not yet delved into that rabbit hole, but I gave you an upvote & favorite; it's actually something I am interested in so I hope you figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assembly is a satellite assembly. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> By definition, satellite assemblies can only contain resources. They
>   cannot contain any executable code.

If you want to access the resources of this assembly - similar code should work:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(
    "ResourceTest.Properties.Resources", 
     Assembly.LoadAssembly(file));
MessageBox.Show(rm.GetString("helloWorldString"));
```

Also, the article from MSDN: [Walkthrough: Loading Resources from a Satellite Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668131%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) shows an alternative way of how to load a resource string from a satellite assembly.

Comment: Good call, can't believe I missed that in the docs.  I'm still not entirely sure if this will work out for me but I will make some modifications based on your suggestion.

Comment: Ended up getting it to work just fine with your method. Marked as the answer.