# Is there a way to reload a localized dll on the fly?

Tags: c#, dynamic, localization

I have a project (WPF) that is using a localization assembly that contains all the resource strings.

This localization assembly is given to a translation service who creates a new localized satellite version of this assembly.

The main application is then supposed to be able to import the newly localized dll. That works, but I can't figure out a way to have the new language available without restarting the application.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Wait... isn't it working depends on local setting? So, if your machine is set with French culture, your app will load French localization, etc? I believe, whatever culture is set on the tread of your app, that will be the language used

Comment: I would say no. I mean... My problem is not to load the right language, it is to add a new one on the fly.When I first load the application, I search for the available languages. If I don't have any localized satellite, I don't have any. Once I add the new one (add the fr-FR directory with the translated dll in the application directory. If I try to refresh the list of available languages, I don't see french. But if I stop and restart the application, it is here...

Comment: Well, you did not show your code how you do it - here is what people do [Load "loose" localized resources at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281109/load-loose-localized-resources-at-runtime)